# Laravel 4 - Catch errors

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

It seems like its not possible to catch errors yourself, insted of getting the laravel 4 error output.

For example if i try:

```
    $databaseConfig = Config::get('database.connections.mysql');
    $connect = mysql_connect($databaseConfig['host'], $databaseConfig['username'], $databaseConfig['password']);
    if (!$connect)
    {
        return 'error';
    }
```

If a error occurs i won't get the "error", insted laravel shows me the exception (on that orange site).

The same if you go ahead and try a

```
try {
    $pdo = DB::connection('mysql')->getPdo();
}
    catch(PDOException $exception) {
    return Response::make('Database error! ' . $exception->getCode());
}
```

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The code you provided should work just fine. If I put this in my routes.php, I see the expected error string (without the orange).

```
Route::get('error', function() {
    try
    {
        $pdo = DB::connection('mysql')->getPdo();
    }
    catch(PDOException $exception)
    {
        return Response::make('Database error! ' . $exception->getCode());
    }
    return 'all fine';
});
```

What might be happening here, is that your PDOException isn't caught. Try added a backslash to the PDOException so you'll be sure it's the one defined in the root and not in the current namespace.

```
catch(\PDOException $exception)
```

Also, try to run the code directly from within the routes.php file and see if it behaves the same.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was the Namespace problem that you pointed out. Didn't know that this works like that. Thanks once again.

Comment: No problem, namespacing problems have caught us all at some point ;-)

Comment: Thanks for teaching me what exception errors are, how they work, and how to handle them.  I've been developing for an embarrassing amount of time without ever understanding what try/catch is all about. Thank you.

Comment: Excelent. Also you could `use PDOException;` in the begging of the file

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this page: http://laravel.com/docs/errors

Quick example:

```
App::error(function(PDOException $e)
{
    Log::error($exception);

    return Response::make('Database error! ' . $exception->getCode());
});
```

Comment: Well you need to add this to the global.php, but that is not what i want. For example if you want to check if the database data is correct, during the instalaltion progress, you want to give out a custom error. A global error handler won't help me there.

Comment: Andrea is right. You can customise your message error when you throw it.

Comment: How? I dont just want to customize the message, sometimes i want to show it on a custom view, sometimes on a blanp page, etc. How can i do that?

Comment: You should be installing Laravel using the Schema builder and migrations. `return Redirect::to('route.name')->withErrors($errormsg);` is a good way to display error messages.

Comment: I dont speak about the laravel installation, i speak about the installation of my application. Where should i put thast redirect in? In the global error handler?

Answer (score 1):

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception) {
echo '<pre>';
echo 'MESSAGE :: ';
    print_r($exception->getMessage());
echo '<br> CODE ::';
    print_r($exception->getCode());
echo '<br> FILE NAME ::';
    print_r($exception->getFile());
echo '<br> LINE NUMBER ::';
    print_r($exception->getLine());
die();// if you want than only
});
```

put this code in your route file...
**you will get ERROR MESSAGE with FILE NAME and ERROR LINE**
all most errors will be covered.

Answer (score 0):

I know my answer is very late. But after referencing from above answers, I hadn't solved the problem.

After looking at this site (very clear explanation here): https://stackify.com/php-try-catch-php-exception-tutorial/

Here is an additional answer:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```